# Change text for UIWebView (dynamically)

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have to change text dynamically in my UIWebView(i don't won't load new html file with new text everytime), but i don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('divID').innerHTML ='%@';",yourcontent]];
```